# Creating a Web Radio

Tags: javascript, html, audio, streaming, audio-streaming

I'd like to develop a web sample application that can send and read audio on the fly.

The idea is to develop a website with HTML5/JS.
So, the admin part (in php or whatever server side language) will allow me to send audio
from a mic.

Then, on the client side, the user can listen to the stream with the `<audio>` tag for example.

Is it possible? Did anybody use a strong (open/free) solution doing that?

Thank you,

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://web.psung.name/zeya/ - this app transcodes your music on the fly and streams it using HTML5. Maybe this will help a little bit ;)

Comment: Does this actually stream the data, or does it just transcode an audio file and send the whole thing? As the question asks for mic input, it would not be an audio file on the server, but a stream instead. I looked at the source, but am not sure if this would work for mic input or similar on the fly.

Comment: I guess it sends the whole thing, but internet radio works thanks to the fact, that mp3's don't have to mark where's the end of the file - and I guess Ogg Vorbis does the same. So we should check if just sending a file infinitely (or splitting it on a smaller chunks and sending partially, and then playing together in a client's browser) would do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much any solution you choose will suffer from bad acceptance on one device or another, and web-based solution is even worse (as extensively pointed out by everybody).

If you want to cover the largest audience possible, set up a streaming server like [Icecast](http://www.icecast.org/) and broadcast over MP3 and/or OGG (both is better). Pretty much every internet connected device with reasonable capabilities will be able to play streaming audio, so let the user pick the appropriate player or its favorite one.

Answer (score 1):

There is a specification for [interacting with devices](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/complete/commands.html#devices), such as microphones, but it is early days and I'm not aware of any support for it.

If you want something that can interact with a mic today, look to Adobe Flash.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can do something like this with *just* JavaScript and HTML5. And if we could, we would most likely have to wait a long while before clients could use it in there browser. Like David said, Flash would work, the problem with that is: A) a lot of devices wouldn't support it and B) Flash is far from free. There are other ways of doing what you described but they would require other programming or at least other plugins. The only other alternative I can think of is Silverlight from Microsoft, free and not overly hard to use, it does have mic support, not sure how great it is though. Hope this helps.

Comment: Here's a link to Microsoft's web site for Silverlight: http://www.silverlight.net/

Comment: Thank for your answer. The problem is that I want to put in place a cross-platform solution. So, I target devices such as iPads ...

Comment: For cross platform Flash is a very bad idea, the iPad does not even support Flash. I doubt it has any support for Silverlight ether though. I see your problem with the mobile market. I'll ask around and see if I can come up with another solution for you. When I come up with something I'll leave another comment here.

Comment: By the way, does the streaming have to be live or is it alright if theres a slight delay?

Comment: Live would be really fantastic ... but if a 5 seconds delay is needed, then I'll see ;)

Comment: I looked around a little to see if I could find I way to do this, I came up with a few ideas. The first one is Shout cast, http://www.shoutcast.com/download, I've never used it myself but it seems like it would work as a streaming solution. Something to look into. Another idea that might work good is icecast.org, again, I've never used it personally but it seems like it would do the job. I'm not sure how well some of these tools will work along with the iPad in particular but I think that there are apps that would allow a user to access them with at most a short delay.

Comment: I ran out of room in the last comment. I know these ideas aren't quite what you were originally looking for, with HTML5 real time streaming and all, but it seems that this is really the best way to go if you want live streaming, and it makes it harder if you are targeting the mobile audience, since most mobile browser are still a little limited. But I commend you for that, trying something like this is a lot of work and you're definitely taking your time researching the topic. I'm looking forward to hearing what you decide on. Maybe you could even post a link to your site here for us to see :)

Comment: @Blake how about NodeJS?

Answer (score 1):

The HTML audio tag does not specify any particular codec, so browser vendors are free to choose their own. Currently, none support a streaming format, although that could happen. As to recording, I'm not sure you'd really want to support unlimited recording from the browser, because you'd have concurrency issues? Would you really allow everybody to record at once?

It seems to make more sense to have a limited access to recording a streaming media session on the server, and then allow archived access to that through the browser. The retrieval could be easily performed with the HTML AUDIO tag, but essentially we've just invented the podcast.

Answer (score 1):

It would be possible to manipulate audio tags to "stream" content, but there'd have to be a buffer of a couple seconds (at least). Re-set the source of the  tag to a URL which provides the next couple seconds every couple seconds (not static files of course, but served dynamically from the stream). Admin side I think you're stuck with a plugin since you need mic access.

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you are proposing is doable in theory, but in practice web clients and standards are still not really mature enough yet. For instance, check out this interesting blog about [audio synthesis in JavaScript](http://acko.net/blog/javascript-audio-synthesis-with-html-5).

Now, for the theory:

Alternative 1: Wait for browsers to add support for a streaming audio format (typically, the audio tag currently supports WAV, OGG and/or MP3).

Alternative 2: Implement streaming yourself...

For the server side (the "mic" audio input thing) I assume you are free to do pretty much whatever you want. For instance, it should be possible to not actually connect the mic to the server, but rather let the server run some sort of transcoder process from another source/server. Then you can have a CGI/FastCGI application that web clients connect to to get the latest stream window (part of the stream, say 1-5 seconds?).

On the web client side, you can probably use the audio tag and control it from JavaScript to update it periodically with new stream windows. Queuing of audio samples is not supported, so you would have to come up with some sort of custom synchronization mechanism. One solution could be to use two simultaneous audio samples that cross-fade (thus minimizing clicks & hickups resulting from inaccurate timing).

Comment: I thought it would be easy to put in place an "Icecast" server that will broadcast an audio stream over an URL. Then, in an HTML page, the audio tag will get it...

Comment: @marcus256 Is this answer still relevant in 2018? I'm looking for ways to make a web radio with JavaScript and NodeJS.

Answer (score 1):

This document on the Apple website might be what you are looking for. It recommends using HTTP Live Streaming for devices like the iPad, iPhone and the iPod Touch: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Might be what you are after.